# JwtSecurityTokenHandler NotSupportedException at EncryptValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jenkins, jwt

I have a `JsonWebTokenFormat` class which creates a JWT token and signs it with a X.509 RSA SSH 256 certificate.

```
internal class JsonWebTokenFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string _issuer;
    private readonly ICertificateStore _store;

    public JsonWebTokenFormat(string issuer, ICertificateStore store)
    {
        _issuer = issuer;
        _store = store;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        RSA rsaPrivateKey = _store.GetCurrentUserPrivateCertificate(_issuer);

        SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPrivateKey), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);

        DateTimeOffset? issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        DateTimeOffset? expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _issuer,
            claims: data.Identity.Claims,
            notBefore: issued.Value.UtcDateTime,
            expires: expires.Value.UtcDateTime,
            signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        string jwtAuthToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);

        return jwtAuthToken;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string jwtToken)
    {
        // read the issuer from the token
        JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtToken);
        RSA rsaPublicKey = _store.GetPublicCertificateForClient(jwtSecurityToken.Issuer);

        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = _issuer,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPublicKey),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken tempToken;
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, tokenValidationParams, out tempToken);

        AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(principal.Identity), new AuthenticationProperties());

        return authenticationTicket;
    }
}
```

And the `ICertificateStore` implementation looks like this:

```
class MockCertificateStore : ICertificateStore
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 _certificate;

    public MockCertificateStore()
    {
        _certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                @"C:\certs\test-client.pfx",
                "12345",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    }

    public RSA GetCurrentUserPrivateCertificate(string subject)
    {
        return _certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    }

    public RSA GetPublicCertificateForClient(string clientId)
    {
        return _certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
    }
}
```

So I have this unit test that tests this class and it works fine on my local machine (and other developers' local machines) but it fails on our Jenkins build environment.

It fails with the following exception:

```
Test method AuthCore.Tests.Token.JsonWebTokenFormatTests.EnsureProtectGeneratesCorrectAuthToken threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Method is not supported.
Stack Trace:
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.DecryptValue(Byte[] rgb)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter.CreateSignature(Byte[] rgbHash)
    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.Sign(Byte[] input) in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\AsymmetricSignatureProvider.cs:line 224
    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateSignature(String inputString, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, SignatureProvider signatureProvider) in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 854
    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token) in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 815
    at AuthCore.Token.JsonWebTokenFormat.Protect(AuthenticationTicket data) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\AuthCore\Token\JsonWebTokenFormat.cs:line 38
    at AuthCore.Tests.Token.JsonWebTokenFormatTests.EnsureProtectGeneratesCorrectAuthToken() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\AuthCore.Tests\Token\JsonWebTokenFormatTests.cs:line 34
```

Any help is appreciated. I've looked at a bunch of SO questions and none of them helped.

Comment: But you didn't mention anything about your build environment. OS, .net version and so on.

Answer (score 1):

## Solved!

The problem was that the `RsaSecurityKey` class has been deprecated since .NET 4.6.0. For some reason, this class is throwing when used in a computer that doesn't have older version of .NET installed, but it was fine on computer with older versions of .NET. Instead, just use `X509SecurityKey` class.

Refer to the following article for potential solution:
https://q-a-assistant.com/computer-internet-technology/338482_jwt-generation-and-validation-in-net-throws-key-is-not-supported.html

```
static string GenerateToken()
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"Test.pfx", "123");
    var securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(certificate);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(),
        Issuer = "Self",
        IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
        Audience = "Others",
        Expires = DateTime.MaxValue,
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
            securityKey,
            SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}

static bool ValidateToken(string token)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"Test.cer");
    var securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(certificate);

    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = "Others",
        ValidIssuer = "Self",
        IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
    };

    var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken securityToken);
    if (principal == null)
        return false;
    if (securityToken == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```